# Make pretty urls in rails. Change /users/ to a database field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

Right now, my urls are being rendered as

```
/users/2/products
```

I know i can use friendly_id to have it render as

```
/users/username/products
```

But I dont want that. In my database `User`, there is a field `role`, which has entries like - `worker`, `janitor` and so on. So, I want to have

```
/users/2/products
```

as

```
/worker/username/products or /janitor/username/products and so on..
```

How do i do it ? Can i use friendly_id to do it ?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know `friendly_id`. I can't even be sure of what you are asking, but something tells me you want to define a custom route.

### Adding a custom route

in your route file, you can add

```
match "/worker/:username/products" => "users#show"
```

and in the action, check for `:username` parameter variable.

```
if params[:username]
  @user = User.find_by_name(params[:username])
else
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

### Routes for your specific case

In your case, it seems that you want this in your route.rb:

```
match "/:role/:username/products" => "users#show"
```

and this in your action to use the params:

```
User.where("role = '?' and username = '?', pararms[:role], params[:username])
```

The route will make accessing a URL like  `/worker/fotanus/products/` end up in the action `User#show` with `params[:role] = 'worker'` and `params[:username] = 'fotanus'`.

Comment: no thats not what i am asking. `worker` is a database entry inside User table. I want to pass that in, in the route. any help on that ? :)

Comment: so what are parameters and what are constants in the route 
`worker/username/products`?

Comment: `:attribute/:username/products` ?

Comment: actually both are `role` and `username` are both stored in the db in the User table

Comment: @psharma I think at this point you already have a good idea of how to create your custom route, but I updated the answer again just in case. Take a look if it fits to you